# Can I add an absolute address to the end of an URL?

Tags: html, http, url, web

I currently have a website where the baseadresse is hardcoded to http://www.site1.com/ 
The site has a number of mediafiles and the relatice paths to these mediafiles are stored in a database. So get to file1.mp3 in folder folder1, I will concatenate the strings to get http://www.site1.com/folder1/file1.mp3 - pretty straight forward.

Now I would like to move the files to another server - let us call that http://www.site2.com - but I don't want to modify the code of www.site1.com. (silverlight code that is not available anymore). Instead I would like to modify the database, so 'folder1' becomes something like http://www.site2.com/folder1 - so that the concatenated string becomes something like:

http://www.site1.com/http://www.site2.com/folder1/file1.mp3 so the file will be gotten from site2 - this syntax obviously does not work, but is there a syntax that does?

Comment: The two 'http' will never work. But if your website has some code that could redirect a specific set of url's to another site, that would be just nail it..  Can be tried with JS also. Try document.url to get the current page url, EDIT it, and redirect using document.location !!

Comment: That is what I was affraid of (but also expecting). I can not add javescript or other code, since the URL is create inside a Silverlight applictaion. All I can do is modify the 'folder' part.

Comment: I don't think you can change the base address in a request purely from database, without ANY code change !!